# Disable SQL detection in JetBrains PyCharm

Tags: python, sql, pycharm

I was trying to type the following line:

```
self._label = QtGui.QLabel("Select parameter from selected category")
```

And PyCharm decided I was doing an SQL Query or something and gave errors about having no data connections configured.  The Syntax Highlighting within the string changed and `Select` and `from` became highlighted like keywords.  Since I don't use SQL or any database whatnot at all (I'm an engineer who programs - I don't use databases, sorry) ... I simply disabled the SQL Plugin in the PyCharm plugin settings.

Is there a less drastic way to disable this auto-inspection behavior in case I ever wanted that plugin turned on?  It seems drastic that any time it sees `Select x from y` in a string it thinks it's an SQL query.  I tried disabling all the SQL inspections under the Inspections settings.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message:

> No data sources are configured to run this SQL and provide advanced code assistance.`

is a little explicit and IMHO a little unnecessary, because I really think that I don't need to configure a database for every project in which we have some SQL queries.

To handle this message, you have two options:

1. Configure a **Data Source** to your project, using the <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> above the message and using the option *Configure a Data Source*:
   [image: Add a data source]

or

2. Disable this *SQL dialect detection* inspection on the Inspection options on the IDE settings:

[image: Disable the SQL dialect detection]

The second option is the best approach for me unless we really want or need a Data Source on your project.

Comment: this does not work for me - i still get the yellow highlights telling me no datasources are configured. Max Carroll's solution solved my issue

Answer (score 25):

To turn off SQL injections go to `Settings | Editor | Language injections` and turn off anything related to SQL.

[image]

Comment: That worked! It sufficed to turn off only `python:"SQL select/delete/insert/update/create"`. Alternative: Turn off *both* Inspections `No data sources configured` *and* `SQL dialect detection`.

Comment: This is the wrong answer. The question is clearly asking for a "less drastic way". The selected answer is correct. The UI has slightly changed and you may need to select more than one option (I searched for SQL and unchecked all) and you can set it to "project default" for rather than "default"

Answer (score 8):

I am using PhpStorm and I have managed to stop it complaining by right-clicking  the error square in the top right then ...

Right click Square > Customize highlighting level > Configure Inspections >

Scroll down to Sql and expand the tree

Uncheck "No Data Sources congirued"

Although you may consider this drastic its the only way, JetBains IDEs are professional tools which have been in development a while, because of the many different requirements of its users it has many options and features.

The settings menu is very clever, you can click

File > Settings > {Then start typing in search : SQL }

Then you can already see the SQL Inspection options including the ones that you want to disable.

When you get used to your IDE of choice, you will be fine

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with pycharm 2019.1 professional edition with this string: 
"Select channel letters from a to c"

The warning message is activated by pycharm IDE when both "Select" and "From" appear in the same string. Rewrite or split the string without one of these two terms and the warning goes away without changing the pycharm SQL warning mechanism.

### Fix 1 of 2:

I eliminated the SQL detection "No data sources are configured..." warning message by removing the word "from" from my string. So the new string without warning in my code is: 
"Select channel letters in the range a to c"

### Fix 2 of 2:

Another solution along this same mindset. Separate the string triggering the warning into two: 1) with the "Select" and 2) the other with the "From". Finally concatenate these two strings together. Again the warning message does not appear since the words "Select" and "From" are now in two separate strings. No change to the original string message was required - no modification to the pycharm SQL warning mechanism - and no warning message. For example in my case: "Select channel letters" + " from a to c" generates no warning.

Comment: Hello! I see that you're new, so let me say thanks for sharing your experience and welcome to the Stack Overflow community!

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in Preferences> Editor> Inspection (⌘-comma for Mac user)
[Here is the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpX5C.png)