# Stop PhpStorm from highlighting SQL

Tags: php, pdo, phpstorm

I want PhpStorm to stop highlighting my SQL queries. I've already had to disable SQL and class method inspection because PhpStorm is having issues with my PDO statements/queries.

However, it is still highlighting my SQL queries in a distracting manner.

See this image for an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijHHl.jpg

How do I remove this highlighting? Or, perhaps someone can recommend a better solution like how to fix the PDO issues with PhpStorm? Using mysql/mysqli functions are out of the question, though.

Thank you.

Comment: what's the PDO issue? I never had any issues with PhpStorm and PDO.

Comment: Which highlighting -- that green background for SQL query? It's standard highlighting for Injected Language fragment.

Comment: @LazyOne yep I figured that out and removed the background color in the style declaration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable SQL detection in JetBrains PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597797/disable-sql-detection-in-jetbrains-pycharm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution was to add my database and set the SQL dialect for the entire project to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Settings -> Plugins
- Look for Database Tools
- Uncheck that plugin (disable it)
- Press Apply
- Restart PhpStorm

This will disable all IDE support for databases. They didn't include switches because it wouldn't make sense to opt out of this wonderful feature.